# how to call a JavaScript method inside th:if from Thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

The title says it all. I have an HTML element like this:

```
<label th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('weight') && 'isModalFirstOpening();'}" th:errors="*{weight}"></label>
```

You can see here that I want to show this label field only when there is an  error in the variable `weight` and that javascript function `isModalFirstOpening()` returns true. However, this code does not work.

Can you help me? Thank you for reading.

Comment: javascripts runs on web browser, thymeleaf runs on the server side..

Comment: Yes I know that.

Comment: Still, there are ways so that th:onclick can bind with a Javascript function. I am looking for such solutions.

Comment: sorry, perhaps i'm being unclear. the `th:if` runs on the server side while [`th:onclick`](https://github.com/engma/thymeleaf-cheat-sheet#attributes) will generate [`onclick`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) attribute on the html element. what you are looking is a backend-frontend integration in general. i personally would go with hidden field approach where `isModalFirstOpening();` is not a js function but rather java method that checks for the said hidden field value.